# Analytic Functions. Prove that $\frac fg$ is analytic and the derivative is ${f'g-g'f\over g^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\Omega$$\subseteq$$\mathbb{C}$ be open and suppose $f$ and $g$ are functions from $\Omega$ into $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose f and g are both analytic on $\Omega$ and $g(z)\neq$0 for all $z\in\Omega$. Prove that ${f\over g}$ is analytic and the derivative is ${f'g-g'f\over g^2}$.

I know that ${f\over g}$ is equal to $f$ multiplied by ${1\over g}$ so since $f$ is analytic I only need to prove ${1\over g}$ is analytic which I'm having trouble doing. I've got as far as $\lim_{h\to 0}$${1\over g(z+h)h}$-${1\over g(z)h}$=${g(z)-g(z+h)\over g(z+h)g(z)h}$
but I'm unsure what to do next

Comment: Do you remember the analogue for the real case? It's the same proof.

Answer (score 2):

Notice $(g(z)-g(z+h))/h=-(g(z+h)-g(z))/h$. Just do it, take the limit! 
$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}-(g(z+h)-g(z))/g(z+h)g(z)h=-g'/g^2$ as $g$ is continuous. This is how we do it!